# unable to select date in calender picker in appium IOS

Tags: appium

I am unable to select birthday date in calender picker in appium IOS. In appium inspector elements are not recognized.

[image]

Comment: may be you want to use adb then, try "adb shell window windows"  may be this can help you

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a WebView to me, As Calendar picker is different in iOS if it is a native view.
Hence, I suggest switching context to webview and check 
Set contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
driver.context("WEBVIEW");